# Need to parse sections of text from repetitive "groupings" of lines within a file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file that contains 3-5 lines of information pertaining to 1 instance of a Multicast group and the file contains multiple instances of Multicast groups:

```
Group: 239.103.0.64
Source: 10.12.49.30/32
Upstream interface: ge-0/0/7.0

Group: 239.103.0.66
Source: 10.12.49.38/32
Upstream interface: ge-0/0/9.0

Group: 239.103.0.71
Source: 10.12.49.2/32
Upstream interface: ge-0/0/0.0
Downstream interface list: 
    xe-5/0/0.0

Group: 239.103.0.72
Source: 10.12.49.6/32
Upstream interface: ge-0/0/1.0
Downstream interface list: 
    xe-5/0/0.0
    xe-5/0/1.0
```

For each instance I would like to produce 1 line of output that contains the Multicast IP address, the source IP address, the Upstream interface and the Downstream interface list with the fields delimited by a "**:**".  I would like the output for the above to look like this:

```
239.103.0.64:10.12.49.30/32:ge-0/0/7.0:
239.103.0.66:10.12.49.38/32:ge-0/0/9.0:
239.103.0.71:10.12.49.2/32:ge-0/0/0.0:xe-5/0/0.0
239.103.0.72:10.12.49.6/32:ge-0/0/1.0:xe-5/0/0.0 xe-5/0/1.0
```

Comment: Hmm.  You say "3-5 lines", but your last group contains 6 lines.  Is that, in fact, the upper limit (or can there be more)?

Comment: You are correct...  It should have worded it "3-n" lines.  A couple of the answers, including yours, were dynamic in nature and worked with 3-n lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pretty but I think it'll do the job.

```
awk -F":" 'BEGIN {RS=""};{$1="";$3=$5=$7=":";gsub(/(\ *)?:(\ *)?/,":");print $0}' test.txt |tr -s " "
```

Comment: Why not just `gsub(/ *: */,":")`?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
        /Group:/                     {g=$2; next}
        /Source:/                    {s=$2; next}
        /Upstream interface:/        {u=$3; next}
        /Downstream interface list:/ {dflag=1; next}
        /^$/ {print g ":" s ":" u ":" d; g = s = u = d = ""; dflag = 0; }
        { if (dflag) { if (d == "") d = $1; else d = d " " $1} }
        END  {print g ":" s ":" u ":" d; g = s = u = d = ""; dflag = 0; }
'
```

- The first three lines of the `awk` program are fairly straightforward:
  capture the values of the Multicast IP address, the Source IP address,
  and the Upstream interface when you see their corresponding labels.
- The fourth line sets a flag so that,
  after we’ve seen the “Downstream interface list” label,
  we know that subsequent (non-blank) lines contain Downstream interfaces.
- It makes more sense to look at the sixth line next:
  If we’ve seen the “Downstream interface list” label,
  collect the listed values, separating them with spaces.
- The fifth and seventh lines are pretty much the same:
  When you get to a blank line, or the end of the file,
  print out the data collected so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind trailing whitespace, you could say:

```
awk -v RS='' -v OFS=':' -F'[:\n] *' '{ print $2, $4, $6, $9 " " $10 }'
```